# find_elements only locates the first result

Tags: python, for-loop, findelement

I am trying to scrape https://edition.cnn.com/ for a school project...I define a method that gets a query as an input and I must get the title, snippet, etc. of all the articles from all the pages...I have used a *for* loop, but it just returns me 10 times the data of the first article on each page...here is my script...

I tried scrolling down the page and defining the results with different locators.

```
while True:

    results=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="cnn-search__result cnn-search__result--article"]')
    time.sleep(5)

    for result in results:

        link,title,date,snippet='NA','NA','NA','NA'

        try:
            linkBox=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="cnn-search__result-headline"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            linkBox=None

        if linkBox:
            link=linkBox.get_attribute('href')

        try:
            titleBox=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="cnn-search__result-headline"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            titleBox=None

        if titleBox:title=titleBox.text

        try:
            dateBox=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="cnn-search__result-publish-date"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            dateBox=None

        if dateBox:date=dateBox.text

        try:
            snippetBox=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="cnn-search__result-body"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            snippetBox=None

        if snippetBox:snippet=snippetBox.text

        writer.writerow([link,title,date,snippet])

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",result)
        time.sleep(1)


    try:
        nextButton=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="pagination-arrow pagination-arrow-right cnnSearchPageLink text-active"]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",nextButton)
        time.sleep(3)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.quit()

        break

fw.close()
```

Comment: What programming language? Python?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Yes,Python.